# Getting data from an Oracle database in Power BI desktop keeps forever

Tags: oracle, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I am trying to get data from a single Oracle database table in Power BI Desktop. This table has around 2 million rows of data.

The following Query works just fine:

```
let
    Source = Oracle.Database("PPM_PROD", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    PPM_DEV = Source{[Schema="PPM_DEV"]}[Data],
    Timesheets = PPM_DEV{[Name="BI_TIMESHEET"]}[Data]
in
    Timesheets
```

However, if I add an SQL statement as below, I run into problems:

```
let
    Source = Oracle.Database("PPM_PROD", [HierarchicalNavigation=true, Query="SELECT * FROM PPM_DEV.BI_TIMESHEET#(lf)WHERE (ACTUAL_TIME > 0) OR (OVERTIME > 0) "]),
    PPM_DEV = Source{[Schema="PPM_DEV"]}[Data],
    Timesheets = PPM_DEV{[Name="BI_TIMESHEET"]}[Data]
in
    Timesheets
```

This query will not get any data and data load/refresh will be stuck at "Evaluating" phase forever. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the first query is not getting the results, just making an offset of the whole data set. The second one is executing a filter to get a specific number of rows that match the condition  of the where. Do you have access to Oracle to show us the execution plan of that query ?

Comment: just a personal observation, after 2 years working with Power BI to create dashboards and reports, I came to realize that it does not work very well with huge volumes of data. In my project, we had to semi-aggregate results in Oracle tables before being able to use this data in reports in Power BI. But, it does not hang, it just takes time.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Oracle at the moment. With the first query in Power Query editor, when I click Close & Apply, the "Evaluating..." phase lasts about a second and data starts to load - slowly but steadily. With the second one, however, I just can't get past the "Evaluating..." phase. This behavior does not seem to be related to the specific SQL above, if I include any SQL (even something as simple as SELECT * FROM PPM_DEV.BI_TIMESHEET), I can't get past the "Evaluating..." phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I'd recommend not using the SQL statement but rather filtering it in the Power Query Editor. In the most common filtering scenarios, Power Query will transform the filter steps applied into a native query similar to your SQL statement.

You can still use a SQL statement if you prefer but the steps

```
    PPM_DEV = Source{[Schema="PPM_DEV"]}[Data],
    Timesheets = PPM_DEV{[Name="BI_TIMESHEET"]}[Data]
```

don't make sense if you've already selected and filtered the `Timesheets` table. Those steps are there to navigate to the schema and table you intend to query but you've already handled that in your SQL.

Comment: You're right; I first navigated to the table and then added the SELECT statement, so the auto-generated M code kept the two lines. I also tried without those two lines, but the result is the same. There seems to be something off when the Query option is included. Filtering in the Power Query Editor worked like a charm, on the other hand. However, there was a catch: The filter should be applied immediately as the first step. If, for example, I first change some column types and then apply the filter, the query is trying to retrieve all the rows before applying the filter.

Comment: Can you rearrange the applied steps in the query editor to filter first? Certain conversions might break query folding, so you may need to put the steps in a particular order for best results.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did and the problem is solved! Thanks for the tip...